# Use test helper function in controller test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to use a test helper function:

```
undefined function myfunction/0
```

the setup is as follows:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.DashboardControllerTest do
  use MyAppWebWeb.ConnCase

  import TestHelpers

  describe "index" do
    setup [:myfunction] #<- This works perfectly
  
    test "some test", %{conn: conn} do
      conn = get(conn, "/")

      var = myfunction #<- This does not work
    end
  end
end
```

The test helper looks like this:

```
# File is located in "support/test_helpers.ex"

defmodule TestHelpers do

  def myfunction(_) do
   #magic!
  end
end
```

It would be great if someone could elaborate! Thanks in advance!

Edit - full stacktrace & version:

```
== Compilation error in file test/myapp_web/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.exs ==
** (CompileError) test/myapp_web/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.exs:41: undefined function myfunction/0
    (elixir 1.11.2) src/elixir_locals.erl:114: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
    (stdlib 3.13.2) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir 1.11.2) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:416: Kernel.ParallelCompiler.require_file/2
    (elixir 1.11.2) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:316: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

```
Elixir 1.11.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 23)


{:phoenix, "~> 1.5.6"},
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. What version of [tag:elixir]/[tag:ex_unit] do you use? Also, please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlekseiMatiushkin - I added the full stacktrace and versions

Comment: I think that the version you shared before editing should work: `def myfunction do` or `def myfunction() do` (arity 0, `myfunction/0`), but `def myfunction(_) do` is a different function of arity 1 (`myfunction/1`). It takes one parameter that it ignores. Could you try removing the `_`?

Comment: Or, alternatively, `var = myfunction(nil)` should also work, or you could add an optional parameter like `def myfunction(_ \\ nil) do` (this would define both `myfunction/0` and `myfunction/1`).

Comment: Are you setting the `test/support/` directory in your `mix.exs` via `elixirc_paths`? I have something like `elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env())` and something specific for the `:test` env via something like: 
`defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... I just needed to change

`import TestHelpers` to `import MyAppWeb.TestHelpers`.